# SQL query limit based of sum()

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to limit my query results based on the sum of column `qty`

For example, this is my database

```
| id | qty | wh | car |
-----------------------
| x1 | 2   | a  | z   |
| x2 | 3   | b  | y   |
| x3 | 10  | a  | z   |
| x4 | 5   | a  | z   |
| x5 | 2   | b  | z   |
| x6 | 2   | a  | z   |
| x7 | 3   | a  | z   |
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE wh = 'a' AND car = 'z' ORDER BY qty LIMIT sum(qty) <= 20
```

As a result I need to get :

```
| id | qty | wh | car |
-----------------------
| x3 | 10  | a  | z   |
| x4 | 5   | a  | z   |
| x7 | 3   | a  | z   |
| x1 | 2   | a  | z   |
```

I think I might need to use a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query, first make a number as an ID `rn`, then accumulation two data set, Judgment is greater than 20

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.qty,t1.wh,t1.car 
FROM (
  select t.*,(@rn:=@rn+1) rn
  from
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM T 
    WHERE wh = 'a' AND car = 'z' 
    ORDER BY qty asc
  ) t CROSS JOIN (select @rn:=0) a
)t1 CROSS JOIN
(
  select t.*,(@rn1:=@rn1+1) rn
  from
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM T 
    WHERE wh = 'a' AND car = 'z' 
    ORDER BY qty asc
  ) t CROSS JOIN (select @rn1:=0) a
)t2 
WHERE t1.rn < t2.rn + 1
group by t1.id,t1.qty
HAVING sum(t2.qty) <= 20
ORDER BY t1.qty DESC
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22740/6

Comment: Thanks mate, it works perfectly!

Comment: We should include a note that the behavior of user-defined variables used in this way (setting a variable and reading it in the same statement) is "not guaranteed". Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html